# Raising priority/sched policy of all thread of a process (linux) chrt?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pthreads, scheduling

I'd like to set SCHED_RR (and priority) on all threads of a particular foreign process.

What would be the best way, to do it from shell 
and another case - programatically from another process when it creates it as a child. 
Thanks!

I suck at shell scripting, and don't know how to run "chrt" for all threads of a process, just in case that matters, threads have different names.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the -a argument.

```
chrt -p -r -a ${mainpid}
```

Note that this wouldn't change the priority of the threads that would start in future after you run chrt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to rise the priority of udevd:

display priority of all threads of a process

$ for p in $(pidof udevd); do chrt -p $p; done

sample output

pid 1249's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 1249's current scheduling priority: 0

pid 1248's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 1248's current scheduling priority: 0

pid 788's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 788's current scheduling priority: 0

rise the priority of all threads of a process

$ for p in $(pidof udevd); do chrt -p 45 $p; done

sample output:

pid 1249's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 1249's current scheduling priority: 0

pid 1249's new scheduling policy: SCHED_RR

pid 1249's new scheduling priority: 45

pid 1248's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 1248's current scheduling priority: 0

pid 1248's new scheduling policy: SCHED_RR

pid 1248's new scheduling priority: 45

pid 788's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER

pid 788's current scheduling priority: 0

pid 788's new scheduling policy: SCHED_RR

pid 788's new scheduling priority: 45

Comment: This doesn't handle threads in the process. You could try something like:

for pid in $(ps -m -o tid --pid $(pidof udevd) | tail -n +3); do chrt -p -r 20 $pid; done